# Create n strings in Python

Tags: python

I get a number (n) from user. 
Just

```
n = int(input())
```

After that, I have to to create **n** strings and get their values from user.

```
i = 0;

while (i < n):
    word = input() # so here is my problem: 
                   # i don't know how to create n different strings
    i += 1
```

How to create **n** strings?

Comment: you need to think about storing the strings: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: unrelated, but it is better Python style to use for-loops in this case.

Comment: you can use a [`list`](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a list, like this:

```
n = int(input())
i = 0
words = []
while ( i < n ):
    word = input()
    words.append(word)
    i += 1
```

Also, this loop is better created as  a for loop:

```
n = int(input())
words = []
for i in range(n):
    words.append(input())
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (python 3):

```
n = int(input())

s = []

for i in range(n):
    s.append(str(input()))
```

The lits s will contains all the n strings.

Answer (score 2):

If you are aware of [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk), you can do this in a single line

```
s = [str(input()) for i in range(int(input()))]
```

int(input()) - This gets the input on the number of strings. Then the for loop is run for the input number of iterations and str(input()) is called and the input is automatically appended to the list 's'.